# MessagingException: MIME part of type "multipart/mixed" contains object of type java.io.File instead of MimeMultipart

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime-types

I'm trying to send email with attachment (pdf or doc(x)). Here is my method. When I'm invoking file.getFile() - it returns me an object java.io.File type

```
public boolean sendEmail(Form form) {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
    try {
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        message.setContent(form.getFile(),"multipart/mixed");
        javaMailSender.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here i'm getting an error:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException; nested exceptions (1) are:_Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: MIME part of type "multipart/mixed" contains object of type java.io.File instead of MimeMultipart [Sanitized]
    at com.my.sender.Sender.sendEmail(Sender.java:37)
    at com.spring.controller.SpringController.update(SpringController.java:133)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
    at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
    at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
    at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
    at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
    at com.liferay.portlet.CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.doFilter(CheckboxParametersPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:68)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:105)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletExceptionAdapter.service(ServletExceptionAdapter.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaMail FAQ describes [how to create a message with an attachment](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#attach) and the [sendfile.java sample program](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/sendfile.java) is a complete example.